# Titanite Slab farming

Tags: dark-souls

I've been looking around online for information concerning where I can farm Titanite slabs., yet all of the information I have found is outdated as the newer versions tend to change quite a few things. Simple question really, where do I need to farm to have a decent chance at these slabs dropping?

Comment: The latest version is 1.08. Is that the version in question? or do you really want information about 1.06? http://darksouls.wikidot.com/game-patches

Comment: It must be 1.08 then. I only assumed it was 1.06 as I haven't seen any info online about it. Where do I find out what version of the game I'm running? Mind you I just recently bought dark souls for the pc within the last month.

Comment: To be honest, it would be better to remove all version information from this question and just to assume "the most recent version at the time of writing". Arqade is designed to be updatable if details change later.

Comment: edited it out, im gonna try some of the stuff listed on that site and will see if i get any results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe [this page](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/titanite-slab) is still accurate.

There are several places to obtain once-per-playthrough slabs, but I believe the [Darkwraith](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/darkwraith-enemy) enemy in New Londo Ruins is the only one that can drop slabs and can be farmed (because it respawns).

I recently got a slab drop from a Darkwraith (and I wasn't even farming for them), but it may have been just before the 1.08 patch was released.

Comment: I meant whichever patch was released a few weeks ago (as of May 1st 2013). I can't remember what the version number is up to. :-)

Comment: thanks for the link, got my first titanite slab drop off of a darkwraith thanks to the info it provided! =)